# Twitter-bootstrap: navbar not showing up on small screens

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am busy with an angular2 project using angular-cli...  I am trying to create a responsive navbar with bootstrap 3 and having some issues...  The navbar displays on my laptop's screen but when I test it in chrome dev tools with the iPhone 5 screen size I can only see the collapse button and the brand text...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  Could it be that jQuery isn't loaded?  If so how can I test if it's loaded (using ng-cli)?

my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">


        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation"><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>                       
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Retail Mobile</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/home']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/checkBarcodes']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span> Check Barcodes</a></li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/stockTake']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Stock Take</a></li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/settings']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>                
            </ul>
    </div>

</nav>


my jQuery import in angular-cli.json:

"scripts": [
        "./../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
      ],
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle for your issus, please

Comment: could you provide the bootstrap version you're using please

Comment: @haxxxton i'm using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently bootstrap 3 doesnt support non "sm" breakpoint "collapse" of menu items. (You appear to be getting some Bootstrap v4 classes mixed in ie. [`navbar-toggleable-md`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#how-it-works)).

Similarly, you're trying to refer to the [v4 toggler](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#supported-content) using `navbar-toggler` and `navbar-toggler-right` when [v3 uses `navbar-toggle`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) and `navbar-toggle-right`.

The last issue is that the `navbar-light` colors are also v4, and so `navbar-toggle`'s `icon-bar` appears white on white without additional css.

**Additional CSS**

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: black;
}
```

**Updated HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Retail Mobile</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/home']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/checkBarcodes']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span> Check Barcodes</a></li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/stockTake']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Stock Take</a></li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['/settings']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xrcxotdd/1/)**

Comment: thanks but it's still not showing up on the smaller display...  What do you mean by "Currently bootstrap 3 doesnt support non "sm" breakpoint "collapse" of menu items. "  Does that mean this isn't possible with bootstrap 3?

Comment: when you say "not showing up" do you mean you dont want to use the "toggle" function to expand and collapse your navigation at small screens? (you can click on the "hamburger" on the right to "show" the links in the fiddle). What i mean is that bootstrap 4 lets you pick the screen size at which it begins collapsing the links, where bootstrap 3 ONLY works at "sm" breakpoint out-of-the-box.

Comment: the toggle navigation button soesn't work at all...  Could it be jQuery?

Comment: What browser are you using? it appears to be working fine in the [jsfiddle in my answer](https://jsfiddle.net/xrcxotdd/1/) on OSX Chrome V 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Comment: i'm using chrome v55.0.2883.87 Windows 10 x64...  I mean when I view it in the responsive design (iPhone 5) device screen size in chrome it doen't do anything when clicked...  Could it be jQuery maybe?  I removed the navbar-light class from the top nav container as well...  I only see the retail mobile header text.

Comment: possibly, are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: if you open the edit fiddle link, and then reduce the size of the pane so that you see the toggle without using the developer tools "device emulator" does it work?

Comment: I now replaced my code with yours and can now see the collapse button when viewing it on a small screen.  It still doesn't do anything when clicked though?  Do you think it's jQuery that's not loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot debug the code that you're seeing locally without more information in your question. You _NEED_ jQuery in order to have bootstrap run, you should include jQuery _BEFORE_ you load bootstrap.js. Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: No errors in the js console...  If you look at my question I show how I added jQuery in my angular-cli.json.  i'm not sure if it's loaded first though...

Comment: Are you loading bootstrap's javascript file too? how?

Comment: No I didn't load bootStrap's Javascript file... Maybe that's what's going wrong here...

Comment: :D.. yep.. i would say that in order to run bootstraps javascript components, you probably need bootstraps javascript :P